# C++ : How to extern a class in c++ / cli windows form apps?

Tags: class, visual-c++, extern

Sorry my bad English first of all.

I just want to use a class globally in my project but i receive some error.
I researched and tried similar titles but didnt work. Maybe i could not do.

### code.h

---

```
#ifndef CODE_H_
#define CODE_H_

class sinif
{

   public:  void doSomeThing()
            {
                 /*
                 ...
                 */
            }
   private:

};

sinif A;

#endif
```

### Form1.h

---

```
//that is main form

#include "code.h"
#include "b.h"

namespace project
{

          /*
          ...

          A.doSomeThing();   // it works  
          */    
}
```

### b.h

---

```
//that is second mini form

#include "code.h"

extern sinif A;

namespace project
{
           /*
          ...

          A.doSomeThing();  //it didn't work
          */    
}
```

Comment: You cannot declare a class *extern*.  The C++ compiler is a single-pass compiler, you have to do the normal thing you need to do and separate the declaration from the definition.  The method that contains the statement must be moved in a .cpp file, one that can #include the required .h files.

Comment: Is  it like yellow answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923392/c-extern-class-declaration     ?

Comment: Your variable needs to be defined in exactly one compilation unit -- you pretty much always want to put the definition in a .cpp file, not a header, for that reason.  (The `extern` declaration does belong in a header, that part is ok.)

Comment: "I receive some error" is not the way to ask a useful question.  Tell us what the error is, or we'll never be able to help.

Comment: @Hans: based on the code, it looks like he means to "extern" *an object of class type*, not the class itself.

Comment: Can you write a sample basicly, please.