# Defined in discarded section error

Tags: c++, class, struct

I have a struct type defined in an header file `myStruct.h` as `struct myStruct {...};`.

Then I have declared one struct object in the main as:

```
myStruct s;
```

And once in a class header in the same way.

This doesn't work, giving an error:

```
`_ZN10myStructC2Ev' referenced in section `...myClass...' 
of.../module.pre.o: defined in discarded section 
`.text._ZN10myStructC2Ev[_ZN10myStructC5Ev]' of .../module.pre.o
```

If I only have the struct in the class it works, but I also need it in the main. How can I solve?

Comment: Can you make an [mcve]?

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923392/c-extern-class-declaration

Answer (score 0):

Define it as :

```
extern myStruct s;
```

in the header file.