# Extern class declaration in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, class, linker

In my Qt5.7 program, I'm trying to implement a solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923392/c-extern-class-declaration) post (@vz0 answer).
I want to access my MainWindow class function from Settings class, but I'm getting an linker error. Please tell me, what am I doing wrong?

Fragment of:

main:

```
MainWindow w; //MainWindow declaration
a.setActivationWindow(&w);
w.setWindowFlags(Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint);
```

mainwindow.h:

```
public:    
static MainWindow* getInstance() { return &mainwindowInstance; }
void trayReload();
void tray();

private:
static MainWindow mainwindowInstance;
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::trayReload()
{
delete trayIcon;
MainWindow::tray();
}
```

settings.cpp:

```
void Settings::bar()
{
MainWindow* mainWin = MainWindow::getInstance();
mainWin->trayReload(); //I want to make this working
}
```

And I'm getting this error after compiling this code:

> settings.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class MainWindow MainWindow::mainwindowInstance" (?mainwindowInstance@MainWindow@@0V1@A)

What should I do in this situation to make it working?

Comment: Please post real code. The code you posted won't compile, and you won't get a linker error using the code you posted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @IInspectable, as you wish, I edited my thread, now this is real code

Comment: This isn't real code. [It won't compile](http://ideone.com/1i5yNP). Better diagnostics [using GCC 5.1](http://ideone.com/StZi4N).

Comment: sorry, I forgot about one static in example code, now [it's compiling](http://ideone.com/cLg8vo), but I still have a linker error in Qt

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of a static class member is incomplete.
Have a look at this line in your header:

```
static MainWindow mainwindowInstance;
```

All this does is *declare* the `mainwindowInstance`. You need to *define* it though (instantiate it). You can do this in your `mainwindow.cpp`:

```
MainWindow MainWindow::mainwindowInstance;
```

Note that you cannot do this in the header file, as then you would end up with multiple instances.

I suggest a completely different design though: Store the instance via a pointer in the class, have a setter for the instance and create it in `main()`, so you can also delete it in `main()` afterwards.

Comment: Please don't answer questions, that are [**exact** duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574407/1889329). As a judicious moderator, you are asked to vote to close the question instead.

Comment: Ok, how can I do it property? When I add MainWindow MainWindow::mainwindowInstance;, compiler says, that 
QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget
and when I place it in Widget constructor compiler says that this is an redefinition.

Comment: That's why I suggested to use a setter and create it in `main()`. You can then follow the Qt guide's way of first creating an application, then the window.